# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycaret.nlp'

Tags: python, module, nlp, pycaret

I'm trying to use `pycaret` with nlp from this [page](https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/learn-pycaret/official-blog/nlp-text-classification-in-python-using-pycaret). Unfortunately, I'm not able to install it. I tried using `pip install pycaret` like described [here](https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/get-started/installation). It is also mentioned in my `pip list`:

```
pip list

Package                   Version
------------------------- --------
pycaret                   3.0.4
```

This is my python version:

```
python --version
Python 3.10.12
```

I also tried to install it from Build from Source like described [here](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret.git@master --upgrade
```

The error is still there:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycaret.nlp'
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error?

---

Please note: I'm using Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NLP module has been removed from PyCaret 3.x if you want to use NLP you can use PyCaret 2.3.10 (the latest version of PyCaret 2) for more information about PyCaret 3.x you can find [here](https://moez-62905.medium.com/announcing-pycaret-3-0-an-open-source-low-code-machine-learning-library-in-python-7479e9190fa1)