# Module Not Found Error: No module named 'pycaret.nlp'

Tags: python, nlp, powerbi, lda, pycaret

I'm trying to use the LDA topic modeling algorithm inside Power BI.

My python environement has the version **Python 3.8.17**

I'm trying to run a Python script inside Power BI

```
from pycaret.nlp import *
dataset = get_topics(dataset, text='cons', model='lda', num_topics=6,learning_decay=0.7)
```

This error I get: [image]

I'm using currently **Pycaret version 3.0.4**. I tried to downgrade the version of **Pycaret to 2.3.10** but other packages will be affected and somehow it starts to generate version confusion for me.

```
DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: Python script error.
<pi>KeyError: 'layout'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError: Cannot 
</pi>
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Python
    DataSourcePath=Python
    Message=Python script error.
<pi>KeyError: 'layout'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError: Cannot 
</pi>
    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.Exceptions.PythonScriptRuntimeException
```

Note that I followed [this article](https://ruslanmv.com/blog/NLP-with-Pycaret-and-Power-BI) (which is 2 years old) that explains the steps on how to apply this on Power BI.

How can I resolve my issue?

Edit: I tried to force downgrade the version thanks to @Quinten using this command:

```
 pip install --force-reinstall -v " pycaret==2.3.10"
```

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76686270/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pycaret-nlp) helps you?

Comment: @Quinten I checked that one, I did on my anaconda powershell pip install 2.3.10 (downgrading the current version) , it's successfully downgraded but I get the second error mentioned above.

Comment: I don't know if you're using power bi too ? @Quinten

Comment: like what are the steps exactly to change the version because all I did is : pip install pycaret==2.3.10 @Quinten

Comment: Hi @userr, I didn't use power Bi, sorry. You could check `pip list` to see your version of the pycaret package?

Comment: @Quinten version 3.0.4

Comment: So probably your package is not downgraded

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip) question about reinstalling python package using pip?

Comment: @Quinten just tried what you told me , i posted the output in the question (I just edited it)

Comment: thanks @Quinten turns out I have to downgrade Pandas too for it to work ! version 1.0.0

Comment: great to hear it works!